# Unable remove underline from text at bottom of page which occurs when mouse is in certain areas

Tags: javascript, html, css, underline

Here is my website: https://memsmosaics.com/#anchor

I can't work out what is making the text in the about section of my website get an underline. It happens when you hover the mouse anywhere in roughly the bottom 60% of the screen - from the bottom few cm of the black section down to the bottom of the white section.
[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the content under the site header is wrapped in tag `a href="#gallery-section"`:

```
<a href="#gallery-section">
   /*content*/
</a>
```

The reason why this happened:

- In `div`, with class `m-container` there is not enough closing tag `</div>`;
- Content is mistakenly wrapped in `a href="#gallery-section"` tag.

Here is a [screenshot](https://ibb.co/rpTZhMS) of the problem area.

Answer (score 0):

this text and many othe code included the video into tag `<a></a>`. and it is work as text for link. if you can edit source this page need move end tag  to upper. source  is big for included to answere. the solution depends on the reason for using the link and its purpose.
since the reason why the entire page is enclosed in a link is not described, you cannot show a single solution. I assumed that the video and the text itself with the js code should not be in the link.
example one of

```
<a href="#gallery-section">
  <div class="windowdiv"></div>
</a>
  <div id="js-content">
    <video poster="images_about/thumbnail.png" controls="">
    <source src="images_about/about.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>

<p>
    Mosaicing offers me boundless possibilities for expression.
My art and technical studies in Italy and Australia have given me the skills needed to mosaic using my favourite material - handmade glass.<br><br>

I love to mix the a variety of handmade glass such as Italian smalti, 24ct gold leaf tesserae, millefiori, stained glass and iridised glass.
Mixed media interests me and I often include found objects, jewellery, bone china, antique glass and ceramic tiles.<br><br>

The technique of placing small pieces of beautiful materials (called tesserae) together to form images enables me to immortalise the creations of my imagination.
</p>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#js-content').load('/gallery.html');

    $('#js-navigation a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#js-content").load(e.target.href);
    })
  });
</script>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
<!--   <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
  <!-- navbar script https://codepen.io/albizan/pen/mMWdWZ -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/navbar_script.js"></script>
```